# Firestore indexing for custom, user-specific document fields

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an application containing categories of elements. Each category has a set of fields defined by the user:

```
Category -> Rooms         Category -> Windows
  Fields                    Fields
    wall-color                frame-material
    wall-height               glass-type
    ...                       ...
```

These defined fields now appear on each element within that category. Each can hold a unique value for each element:

```
Office 100              Office 200             Window A
  wall-color: blue        wall-color: red        frame-material: metal
  wall-height: 13'-7"     wall-height: 10'-0"    glass-type: double
```

Now I want users to have the ability to query their elements based on the values in these custom fields:

```
this.firestore.col(`/projects/elements`,ref => ref.where('wall-color','==','blue'))
```

The problem is since these field ids are user-defined and custom to every user, I cannot index them ahead of time. Any ideas on how to properly structure this or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand that you need to know the list of (existing) values for each field **for each user**, in order to build the queries (e.g. in the front-end with drop down lists showing the existing values), you could store these values in a user profile document, possibly in some arrays.

It means that, for example, when you write a new `Room` document you update the user profile with the new `wall-color` value (using a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)).

You would query this user profile document when the user opens the app.

Comment: @zsoflin Hi, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?